# Case insensitive approach for sugarcrm retrieve_by_string_fields() function

Tags: php, sugarcrm, case-insensitive, suitecrm

Is there any case-insensitive approach for the bean method retrieve_by_string_fields() in sugarcrm. What we want is that when retrieving using a name Akshay and akshay should both return the same bean.

Kindly guide me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it can be done using retrieve_by_string_fields, though one solution would be to use sql to first get the bean-id, and then fetch the bean using the id.

Example using accounts module;

```
$name = "Akshay";
$db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
$id = $db->getOne("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE name = '$name' AND deleted = 0");
if (!empty($id)) {
    $account = BeanFactory::getBean("Accounts", $id);
}
```

Comment: Hi @ogge7, I overridden the method retrieve_by_string_fields to accept one more parameter and managed to get it working. Thanks for your answer.